# Counting valleys from a sequence of steps where each step is either 'U' or 'D'. What is the time complexity of this solution?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, if-statement, time-complexity

Given a sequence of up and down steps. Find and return the number of valleys in the given sequence.
We always start and end at the sea level, and each step up or down represent one unit change in altitude.

- A mountain is a sequence of consecutive steps above sea level, starting with a step up from sea level and ending with a step down to sea level
- A valley is a sequence of consecutive steps below sea level, starting with a step down from sea level and ending with a step up to sea level.

**Example:** If the path is 'DDUUUUDD', first we enter a valley two units deep.Then we climb onto a mountain two units high.Finally we return to the sea level. Therefore we return one.

**Question:** Is the time complexity of the given solution O(n / 2) or O(n), and how does an if statement change the complexity of an algorithm ?

**Solution:**

```
def countingValleys(n, s):

altitude = 0
prev_a = 0
v_count = 0

for i in range(1, n, 2):
    if s[i] == s[i-1]:
        if s[i] == 'D':
            altitude -= 2
            prev_a = altitude + 1
        else:
            altitude += 2
            prev_a = altitude - 1
    else:
        if s[i] == 'D':
            prev_a = altitude + 1
        else:
            prev_a = altitude - 1

    if altitude == 0 and prev_a == -1:
        v_count += 1

return v_count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BigO notation does not care about the factor 1/2. `O(n)` and `O(n/2)` are still O(n) - albeit one might be slightly faster in practice.

Your problem has to touch each element once so its O(n) - having `if`s inside does not really effect this.

If you want the practical faster way to do things, benchmark it. read about the timeit module here: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/timeit.html

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

You could also streamline your implementation:

```
def countingValleys(string):
    """returns number of sea levels touched and current level 
    as tuple (sealevels_touched, current_level)"""
    level = 0
    valleys = 0
    for c in string:
        if c == "D":
            if level == 0:
                valleys += 1
            level -= 1 
        else:  
            level += 1

    return valleys 

print(countingValleys("DDUDDUUUUUUDDDUDUUDUUDUUUDDDDDD")) # 2
print(countingValleys("DDUUDUUD")) # 2
```

No need for enumerate or indexing at all.

Comment: @Hello added alternate implementation to show its a O(n)

Comment: Thank you for the quick and informative answer. Accepted.I have one more question regarding the time complexity but i will  form another question instead of asking you here in the comment section.If you could check that it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have checked your solution and it counts the mountains as well. It should return only the number of valleys in the given sequence, and doesn't accommodate for the fact that we always start and end at the sea level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method will take less time to execute

Does level=0 valley=0 make any difference, they both are similar level=valley=0

The logic is simple you just have to count if the no if "U"-uphill assigned as '1' and number of 'D'-Downhills assigned as '-1' and on adding the both count one should get '0' as in [DDDUUU] which will increment valley by '1'.

```
def countingValleys(n, s):
    count=0
    count1=0
    for i in s:
        if (i == "U"):
            count += 1
            if (count == 0):
                count1 += 1
        else:
            count -= 1
    print(count1)
```

The method is simple